# Testcases for a C interpreter

Tags: c, testing, compiler-construction, case, interpreter

I would like to test a little ANSI C interpreter.
My tool interprets my C program. It doesn't produce machine code; and I can't access the heap/stack after execution!
I was thinking of validating return values / outputs against GCC or something like this.

I was searching for something that fits for me, but i hardly found anything FREE or open source.

Does anybody have an idea/suggestion how to test my interpreter?
Can anybody recommend something like a test suite; or a package of test cases?

Comment: You could take the linux kernel if your interpreter is complete enough. It's all C and assembler AFAIK.

Comment: this would not work for me - i would like to start implementing my interpreter with a small c subset and extend it step by step (for example at the beginning without arrays)

Comment: @RedX actually the Linux kernel is not C but GNU C...

Comment: i was more thinking about simple arithmetic tests; function calling tests; some pointer arithmetic and so on

Comment: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/pldi11-preprint.pdf

Comment: i already looked at Csmith; the problem is, that this testcases try to crash the compiler. thats one step ahead - first of all i would like to test basic operations/statements and so on - and atm i'm not able to interpret libraries and so on

Comment: @matg, Csmith is quite configurable, you can produce sequences of simple statements, limit its output to whatever subset you like, compare different compilers/interpreters behaviour, etc. Or, alternatively, you may want to implement a similar random code generation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote a C interpreter and mainly relied on the gcc.c - torture/execute test cases. This test suite consists of ["code fragments which have historically broken easily"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs//gccint/C-Tests.html). The advantage of this test cases is, that they have to be executed to provide a result (and not, e.g., only compiled) and then the result is matched to an expected result. You do not need to compare it with the result of an executed program, that was compiled by GCC. You basically just need to include the files in the directory and execute them which contrasts some other test suites, where you have to parse expected results from configuration files or similar. You can download the tests from the [GCC repository](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs//gccint/C-Tests.html).

One disadvantage for you might be, that the test cases are often extensive and can also include GNU extensions such as the *asm* statement for executing assembler code or attributes on how to align memory content. They also include some test cases for some old K&C function style notation like in the following example (not taken from the suite):

```
int func(a)
int a; 
{
    return a + 1;
}
```

However, I still would recommend you to look through the test cases and see what you can execute, as they also test many "normal" corner cases for ASNI C.